# List of Android devices benchmarks

Tags: benchmarks

Are there any solid reference websites where I can compare benchmarkings of various Android devices? Similar to sites like [CPU Benchmark](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/) and [Video Card Benchmark](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/) for PC devices.

Comment: Have you tried an internet search for it? [This was the first result](http://browser.primatelabs.com/android-benchmarks) on Google for "android benchmarks" and it seems to fit the bill.

Comment: I thought it would be an interesting topic to be covered on this site.

Comment: While I can't say this is off-topic with any authority, I recommend reading the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page. While this kind of question is not expressly forbidden, it doesn't seem to fall into our standard format of questions which are about 1: using your Android device, 2: using a particular app on your Android device, or 3: trying to solve an error or other issue in using your Android device.

Comment: I have read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and my question doesn't seem to be off-topic by those standards as well. My only intention by asking it was to help android owners who want a way of comparing their devices when deciding to purchase a new device. I know it is quite useful to me, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PassMark has a quite comprehensive list of [Android devices with CPU, memory, storage, 2D graphics and 3D graphics benchmarks](http://www.androidbenchmark.net/). If your device is not on the list, you can use the [free app on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.passmark.pt_mobile) to measure your device (and contribute to the public list).

[image]